# How to fit a two phase exponential decay curve?

Tags: r, nonlinear-regression, error-message

I have a model where the variable y theoretically should have an exponential decay over time x. The real data showed a fast decay to begin with and a slower decay towards the end. Here is the code:

```
x <- c(300, 600, 900, 1200, 1500, 1800, 2100, 2400)
y <- c(0.461753, 0.350268, 0.315898, 0.282984, 0.255779, 0.225342, 0.19660, 0.170814)
fitData <- data.frame(x,y)

plot(x, y, type="b", xlab="tdecay", ylab="fvpfmpdecay")

# a is plateau. b is the amplitude of fast phase, r1 is the fast constant. 
# (y[1]-a-b) is the amplitude of slow phase, r2 is the slow constant.
f = function (a, r1, r2, b) {
  a + (b * exp(-(r1 * x))) + ((y[1]-a-b) * exp(-(r2 * x)))
}
fit <- nls(f, data=fitData, start=list(a=0.25, r1=0.05, r2=1e-5, b=0.22), 
           algorithm="port")
```

As a result, I got the “Error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable”.

Questions:

1. What I need to get here are the fast and slow constant of the slope in this decay.
2. I made up the start values by experience, are there sophisticated ways to do it?

Comment: Error messages like the one you received usually mean a syntax error in setting up or using a function. In your case, I suspect that the `y[1]` (a subsetting) in your function definition of `f` is not passing through to the call to `nls` in the way that you had hoped.